# HTML5 <video> Element Won't Work on Android

Tags: android, html, mobile, video, html5-video

I'm building a mobile site and haven't been able to get a HTML5 video element to work on my Samsung Galaxy S with Android 2.2.

The embedded video element at http://mediaelementjs.com/ DOES work.

However, the video element I created at http://mattjennings.net/zzz/video-test/test.php  DOESN'T work. As you can see I'm also using code from Media Element JS Listed above.

I've spent hours trying to solve this problem including converting the test.mp4 file in my example link above to an "Android ready format" with Videora Android Converter.

Comment: Which browser are you using on Android?
The native one, Opera, ..?

Comment: The source shows that you included a video with a different base file name for the mp4-format. The URL seems to work, but is this the right video?

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to paly in video in emulator or in device. If it is not playing in the emulator it is the problem of video resolution. Best to try video of low resolution. I have gone through same problem.

Comment: A very good thought but @risingPhoenix1979 does say "on my Samsung Galaxy S"

Comment: Then for android 2.2 it partially supports <video> tag

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below url it may help you

The Android browser (before 2.3) requires  [specific handling](http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/) to run the video element.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using HandBrake (https://handbrake.fr/), which is free and open source software, to create MP4 files for a website that could play on my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone that runs Android 2.2.

I also used code from http://www.mediaelementjs.com/ to make this work.